# What shape does the fundamental polygon $A^{-1} B A^{-1} B$ represent?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I have been looking at the following fundamental polygon: $A^{-1} B A^{-1} B$.

After thinking about it I believe this should create a torus, is this right? And if not what shape does it create?

I suspect I am wrong because this [article](http://brickisland.net/cs177/?p=94) suggests that the only fundamental polygons that create a torus are: $A B A^{-1} B^{-1}$ and a hexagonal one.

Comment: Have you drawn the unit square with these sides?

Comment: @RahmaAlfarsy: I added a picture to explain the part about the projective plane. Maybe this was not obvious for you. I hope the answer is acceptable, now.

Comment: @DanielBernoulli Thank you the diagrams were very useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed $ABA^{-1}B^{-1}$ represents the torus. As you can see [in this animation.](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus#/media/File:Torus_from_rectangle.gif)

$ABAB$ represents the projective plane. For further information visit [Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_projective_plane) Here is a picture:

[image: real projective plane]

EDIT: Maybe it is not that obvious to you, but by cutting the square of the representation $A^{-1}BA^{-1}B$ along the diagonal line and by gluing things in another order, we get exactly the projective plane $ABAB$ (with the picture anove) or $C^2$ (as in the picture below).

[image: real projective plane 2]